# Is it true that the probability $\mathbb{P}(S > t)$ is equal to $\int_0^t \mathbb{P}(S > x) \, dx$?

Tags: probability, integration

I have a question about the following equality
$$\int_0^t \mathbb{P}(S > x) \, dx = \mathbb{P}(S > t),$$
where $S$ is a positive random variable. I can't see why this equality should hold. It means
$$\int_{0}^t (1 - F_S(x)) \, dx = 1 - F_S(t),$$
where $F_S$ is the distribution function of $S$.

So the area of $1-F_S(x)$ between 0 and $t$ is equal to the value $1 - F_S(t)$.

I have a feeling that the equality is wrong, because when you take the limit you get
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t \mathbb{P}(S > x) \, dx = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(S > t) = 0$$
and I'm quite sure that
$$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(S > x) \, dx \neq 0.$$

In conclusion: is the equality wrong or am I blind?

Comment: Here's something that is true: $\int_t^\infty \mathbb{P}(S > x) \, dx = \mathbb{E}(S-t)^+$. (Key word: layer cake representation)

Answer (score 4):

The equality is quite definitely wrong.  Try any example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ then $P(S>x)=(1-x)$ and so according to your formula we should have $P(S>t)=\int_0^t P(S>x)dx=t-1/2t^2$. Plug in $t=1/3$ and you get $P(S>1/3)=1/3-1/18$. But clearly $P(S>1/3)=2/3$ so the equation is complete nonsense.